# How can I run gllamm for each identified subgroup?

Tags: stata

I have to program an ado file to conduct subgroups meta-analysis using `gllamm`. Even though I have the gllamm command within the loop in which each command runs for each subgroup separately, in the results the number of studies included in the `gllamm` execution is the total number of studies from the dataset, so it does not run separately for each subgroup, but runs the same `gllamm` command for each subgroup. Any suggestions how can I fix this?

```
local i=1
while `j'<=`ngroups' {  
qui count if (newby==`j')
    if r(N)==0{
    di "Subgroup analysis can not be completed"
    }
    qui sum `1' if newby==`j'
    scalar `k'=r(N)
    di in ye "The number of studies included in this meta-analysis is " `k'
qui levelsof `2' , local(slev)
foreach i in `slev' {
    if `i'<=0 {
        di as err "Varlist s should only contain positive values" 
        exit 125
        }
}
    eq het: `2'
    constraint define 1 `[s1]'`2'=1

    gllamm `1', i(id) s(het) nats constraint(1) level(`l') adapt prior(gamma, scale(10000) shape(2))
  
local j=`j'+1
}
}
```

Comment: The code is nowhere near self-contained or self-explanatory. Nevertheless some comments that may help seem possible. The main problem is that your `gllamm` call is always the same, given local macro `1`. I've highlighted several other problems. It's not wrong, but using `while` to increment is old-fashioned. `forvalues` is more modern style.

Answer (score 2):

```
local i=1
* presumably local j = 1 before this 
* presumably local ngroups defined before this 
while `j'<=`ngroups' {  
    qui count if (newby==`j')
    if r(N)==0 {
        di "Subgroup analysis can not be completed"
        * !!! you need to get out of the loop here 
    }
    qui sum `1' if newby==`j'
    * summarize, meanonly better style 
    scalar `k'=r(N)
    di in ye "The number of studies included in this meta-analysis is " `k'

    qui levelsof `2' , local(slev)
    * !!! shouldn't this also be for the current group of newby 
    * !!! why don't you insist here that you only want positive values 

    !!! you're already using i as a local macro name 
    foreach i in `slev' {
        if `i'<=0 {
             di as err "Varlist s should only contain positive values" 
             exit 125
        }
    }

    eq het: `2'
    constraint define 1 `[s1]'`2'=1

    * !!! this is the same every time Stata gets to here 
    * !!! so long as local macro 1 is the same 
    * !!! you may need to slap -if- conditions on the command 
    * !!! Stata won't select a subset just because you are inside a loop 
    gllamm `1', i(id) s(het) nats constraint(1) level(`l') adapt prior(gamma, scale(10000) shape(2))
  
    local j=`j'+1
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so how exactly can i change this ?

Comment: Add the appropriate -if- condition on the -gllamm - command.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please? Thank you very much for all your help so far!

Comment: Presumably the same `if` condition applies as earlier and perhaps it should be more restrictive. The code must follow from the statistics you are trying to do, which you don't fully explain and which isn't the focus here.

Comment: Offering exact code could be taken as implying that I understand exactly what your code should do, and I really don't.